# Basic Jax-RS PATH configuration at method level rather than class level

Tags: java, spring, url, spring-boot, jax-rs

I have a question and cant figure out for a long while since I just started with JAX-RS. Can we specify path with method rather than class. I am trying to run it but it does not work.

```
@Path("/images")
@Component
@Transactional
public class ImageResource {


    @GET
    public List<Image> getAll(){
        return this.imageDao.findAll();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to have something like this:

```
@Component
@Transactional
public class ImageResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/images")
    public List<Image> getAll(){
        return this.imageDao.findAll();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From @path documentation:

> Identifies the URI path that a resource class or class method will
>   serve requests for.

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Path.html

So you can annotate classes and methods, but you can't skip class annotation. I would suggest you using:

```
@Path("/")
@Component
@Transactional
public class ImageResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/images")
    public List<Image> getAll(){
        return this.imageDao.findAll();
    }
}
```

Also it's seems strange to me that you:

1) Have @Transactional annotation on your controller class. I believe it should be placed on imageDao. Furthermore be sure that all methods require transactions. If no - place this annotation only on needed methods.

2) Your controller class is called "ImageResource". It's better to call such classes as *Controller. In your case ImageController.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these tips. I just started with it so I am not aware of many conventions. I also am guilty of putting things in my code which I dont completely understand.